# PageViewController on Xamarin will not load child content

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am quite new to mobile dev so forgive me if some of this seems trivial. But I am trying to get a basic PageViewController working in Xamarin iOS with a number of different sign up controllers I have, for different stages of the app signup. So a user will fill in page one, click continue and be taken to step two and so forth.

I used a sample PageViewController project from GitHub and got that working on my simulator fine. However when I try and use it with my sign up controllers, I get an error

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key DateOfBirthText.

This is the parent view controller OnLoad method

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            _pageViewController = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SignInPageViewController") as UIPageViewController;
            _pageViewController.DataSource = new PageViewControllerDataSource(this, _userInput);

            var startVc = ViewControllerAtIndex(0);
            var viewControllers = new[] {startVc};

            _pageViewController.SetViewControllers(viewControllers, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, false, null);
            _pageViewController.View.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Size.Height - 50);
            AddChildViewController(_pageViewController);
            View.AddSubview(_pageViewController.View);
            _pageViewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(this);            
        }
```

It throws the error on line

```
_pageViewController.SetViewControllers
```

And this is the designer code for the child controller that tries to be loaded into the PageViewController and throws the error

```
{
    [Register ("SigninViewControllerStageOne")]
    partial class SigninViewControllerStageOne
    {
        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UITextField DateOfBirthText { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UITextField NameText { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UIButton NextStepButton { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UITextField PhoneNumberText { get; set; }

        [Outlet]
        [GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
        UILabel TitleLabel { get; set; }

        void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
        {
            if (DateOfBirthText != null) {
                DateOfBirthText.Dispose ();
                DateOfBirthText = null;
            }
            if (NameText != null) {
                NameText.Dispose ();
                NameText = null;
            }
            if (NextStepButton != null) {
                NextStepButton.Dispose ();
                NextStepButton = null;
            }
            if (PhoneNumberText != null) {
                PhoneNumberText.Dispose ();
                PhoneNumberText = null;
            }
            if (TitleLabel != null) {
                TitleLabel.Dispose ();
                TitleLabel = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update: Full stack trace

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name:
>   NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key DateOfBirthText.
>
> Native stack trace:
>
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00958494
>   __exceptionPreprocess + 180
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x08fd3e02
>   objc_exception_throw + 50
>
> 2   CoreFoundation                      0x009580b1 -[NSException
>   raise] + 17
>
> 3   Foundation                          0x014777f8
>   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
>
> 4   Foundation                          0x013d1e6a
>   _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 115
>
> 5   Foundation                          0x013d1def
>   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 295
>
> 6   UIKit                               0x0397b931 -[UIViewController
>   setValue:forKey:] + 85
>
> 7   Foundation                          0x0140654b
>   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 384
>
> 8   UIKit                               0x03bf8a62
>   -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 132
>
> 9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x08fe800c -[NSObject
>   performSelector:] + 62
>
> 10  CoreFoundation                      0x00881131 -[NSArray
>   makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 273
>
> 11  UIKit                               0x03bf70fc -[UINib
>   instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2102
>
> 12  UIKit                               0x03983380 -[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 429
>
> 13  UIKit                               0x03983db8 -[UIViewController
>   loadView] + 189
>
> 14  UIKit                               0x039841c4 -[UIViewController
>   loadViewIfRequired] + 154
>
> 15  UIKit                               0x03984ab1 -[UIViewController
>   view] + 35
>
> 16  UIKit                               0x04038649
>   -[UIPageViewController _setViewControllers:withCurlOfType:fromLocation:direction:animated:notifyDelegate:completion:]
>   + 2250
>
> 17  UIKit                               0x0403a76a
>   -[UIPageViewController setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:] + 309
>
> 18  ???                                 0x1a6a07cc 0x0 + 443156428
>
> 19  ???                                 0x1a69f6d0 0x0 + 443152080
>
> 20  ???                                 0x18d3200f 0x0 + 416489487
>
> 21  ???                                 0x18d29c1d 0x0 + 416455709
>
> 22  BarPandaApp                         0x001be859
>   mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 921
>
> 23  BarPandaApp                         0x0027d0ce
>   mono_runtime_invoke + 142
>
> 24  BarPandaApp                         0x0035e225 xamarin_trampoline
>   + 5605
>
> 25  UIKit                               0x0397fb72 -[UIViewController
>   _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 44
>
> 26  UIKit                               0x03984692 -[UIViewController
>   loadViewIfRequired] + 1384
>
> 27  UIKit                               0x039d02bb
>   -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 52
>
> 28  UIKit                               0x039d0b75
>   -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 421
>
> 29  UIKit                               0x039d0d1c
>   -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 145
>
> 30  UIKit                               0x039d2118
>   -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1038
>
> 31  UIKit                               0x039d339e
>   -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 68
>
> 32  UIKit                               0x03bb84b7
>   -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 252
>
> 33  UIKit                               0x038843d4
>   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 810
>
> 34  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x08fe8059 -[NSObject
>   performSelector:withObject:] + 70
>
> 35  QuartzCore                          0x0b607096 -[CALayer
>   layoutSublayers] + 144
>
> 36  QuartzCore                          0x0b5fa8b6
>   _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 388
>
> 37  QuartzCore                          0x0b5fa71a
>   _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
>
> 38  QuartzCore                          0x0b5ecee7
>   _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 317
>
> 39  QuartzCore                          0x0b621847
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 561
>
> 40  QuartzCore                          0x0b622108
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
>
> 41  CoreFoundation                      0x0086a75e
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 30
>
> 42  CoreFoundation                      0x0086a6be
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 398
>
> 43  CoreFoundation                      0x0085f868
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 504
>
> 44  CoreFoundation                      0x0085f65b CFRunLoopRunInMode
>   + 123
>
> 45  UIKit                               0x037ae2da -[UIApplication
>   _run] + 540
>
> 46  UIKit                               0x037b3eb9 UIApplicationMain
>   + 160
>
> 47  ???                                 0x18d27144 0x0 + 416444740
>
> 48  ???                                 0x18d26ef4 0x0 + 416444148
>
> 49  ???                                 0x18d249a0 0x0 + 416434592
>
> 50  ???                                 0x18d24620 0x0 + 416433696
>
> 51  ???                                 0x18d24823 0x0 + 416434211
>
> 52  BarPandaApp                         0x001be859
>   mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 921
>
> 53  BarPandaApp                         0x0027d0ce
>   mono_runtime_invoke + 142
>
> 54  BarPandaApp                         0x002822d1
>   mono_runtime_exec_main + 401
>
> 55  BarPandaApp                         0x00282095
>   mono_runtime_run_main + 645
>
> 56  BarPandaApp                         0x0013a3d5 mono_jit_exec +
>   213
>
> 57  BarPandaApp                         0x0036d73a xamarin_main +
>   2474
>
> 58  BarPandaApp                         0x0036e351 main + 65
>
> 59  libdyld.dylib                       0x094ada25 start + 1

Comment: What is the full error message (there should be some **at** lines after the clipped message in your question , i.e.: `at (wrapper managed-to-native) .... at ..... at .....`

Comment: Just added the full stack trace

Comment: Intrestingly when I remove the Names I've given each of the controls (In the VS IDE designer properties window) and just leave them as default controls with no short names to reference them by, it works

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't think you should use UIPageViewController to implement the sign up progress.

But if you just need it, there is a sample I wrote for other, you can check this link to get it:

[xamarin.ios implement PageController with images only code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805639/xamarin-ios-implement-pagecontroller-with-images-only-code/38814779#38814779)

I suggest you to use UINavigationController, It can make all you need, there is an example:

This is the code for AppDelegate(override the method "FinishedLaunching"):

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        SignUpStepViewController step1 = new SignUpStepViewController (1, UIColor.Red);
        SignUpStepViewController step2 = new SignUpStepViewController (2, UIColor.Green);
        SignUpStepViewController step3 = new SignUpStepViewController (3, UIColor.Blue);
        step1.SetNextController(step2);
        step2.SetNextController(step3);

        UINavigationController myNavigationController = new UINavigationController (step1);
        this.Window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        this.Window.RootViewController = myNavigationController;
        this.Window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
        return true;
    }
```

This is the code for SignUpStepViewController:

```
public class SignUpStepViewController : UIViewController
{
    public SignUpStepViewController (int index,UIColor color)
    {
        this.Title = "Step " + index;
        this.View.BackgroundColor = color;
    }

    public void SetNextController(SignUpStepViewController nextC)
    {
        UIBarButtonItem btnContinue = new UIBarButtonItem ("Continue",UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, delegate {
            this.NavigationController.PushViewController(nextC,true);
        });
        this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem (btnContinue,true);
    }
}
```

Hope it can help you.

If you still need help, just leave the message here, I will check latter.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the code snippet. I will try with the navigation controller tonight and see how it works out. I'm still trying to get my head around the best controllers and framework to use in different situations so this helps a lot. Incidentally do you happen to have a link to a good tutorial that explains all the different navigation controller types in IOS and when to use each one?

Comment: I tried this code but inside the UIViewController, this.NavigationController is null

Comment: One thing though, I created my View Controllers in the VS graphical design editor. I have created an instance of it and passed it to the navigation controller as you did above, however it just loads a black screen, it doesnt load any of the controls or content I created in that controller in the GUI editor. Is there a step missing?

Comment: I have no experience about the VS graphical design editor, I always use OS X to develop. But for sure thing is that you need to make the NavigationController as your app window's RootController. About the black screen, try to set a Frame to the ViewController's view you pushed, like "this.View.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds". If you still can't solve it, Can you post some code or screenshot to let me know more clearly about the issue.  About the tutorial, I suggest Apple's documents.