# Xamarin.iOS ScrollView with the use of UIPageViewController, UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, uipageviewcontroller

I'm currently trying to implement a scroll interface the same as this https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/FrogScroller/ but instead of scrolling images I want to scroll UIViews. I'm trying to reverse engineer this solution but it's proving difficult. Does anyone know of an example that already exists for this? Or can anyone suggest how best to achieve this UI? I would have thought this was a common UI, allowing the user to swipe to new screens.

Basically, my app will show a screen which has a list of images based on a subject. The user can swipe left to move to the next subject which swipes the screen along to show the next screen which lists the images about the next subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the UIPageViewController, I have wrote a sample for others, you can check this link:

[xamarin.ios implement PageController with images only code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805639/xamarin-ios-implement-pagecontroller-with-images-only-code/38814779#38814779).

Customize the ContentViewController, you can put anything you want, or make your own CustomViewController（with the Index property） to instead of it.

Hope it can help you.

If you still have any questions, leave it here.

Comment: Amazing work Alanc this does exactly what I need! Thank you

Comment: Very glad to help you.