# how to create a carouselview with page indicator using xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

There is a pagecontrol and uipageviewcontroller in xamarin ios.
I need to create a coach screen for ios with a carouselview and a pageindicator .
I am not able to use uipageviewcntroller as the default transition style is not scroll and I am adding the pageviewcontroller programmatically. 
So I have to go for pagecontrol with a scrollview.
I am not able to achieve that and facing some issue.

Comment: Is there anyway that I can add a scrollview and pagecontrol in the middle of the page? Is there any sample available for that?

Answer (score 0):

About the PageViewController, I have wrote a sample for others, you can take a look:

[Xamarin.iOS implement PageController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805639/xamarin-ios-implement-pagecontroller-with-images-only-code/38814779#38814779)

You can add anything you want in any page's content view controller.

Hop it can help you.